# How to disable mousedown event on Silverlight listbox

Tags: silverlight

I have a third-party image control inside an SL5 listbox itemtemplate.  This makes for a nice scrollable gallery of images.

Now for the trouble: the third-party image control (LeadTools v17.5) has an interactive feature wherein mouseleftbuttondown causes a draggable magnifying glass to appear. This works great when the control is not hosted in a listbox.  But clicking on the control within a listboxitem does nothing.  After some research I "believe" this is because the listboxitem is trapping the mouseleftbuttondown event marking it as handled so the image control never sees it.  In my application I have no need to handle the mouseleftbuttondown event at the listbox level (other buttons etc control my UI).  Assuming I'm correct, is there a way to stop the listboxitem from listenting to this event?

Or perhaps I'm completely wrong about the cause.  In that case any other ideas about why the listbox appears to block mouseleftbuttondown events from reaching the controls within is appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to keep the `ListBoxItem` from handling the event, you might be able to use [`UIElement.AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) with `handledEventsToo: true`, if you can get the necessary `UIElement` and `Delegate` references to trigger the image control's feature.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions.  In this case it turns out the quick solution was to add this handler to the image control:

```
    private void leadGalleryImageViewer_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

From this I gather the mouseleftbuttondown event was being received by the image control all along, but likely as it bubbled up through the listitem and beyond, the listitem did its thing then marked it as handled effectively killing anything the image control was trying to do.  By marking the event as handled at the image control level, the listitem ignores it.